# PostgreSQL: Display and count distinct occurrences of values across multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 9.4.1, I am trying to identify/display the occurrences of values over 3 different columns.  See below (apologies for the formatting, I can't get a proper table format.  Type, type1 and type2 are the column names. The table name is `documents`

```
CREATE TABLE documents
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES 
    ('USA','China','Africa'),
    ('China','USA','Chemicals'), 
    ('Chemicals','Africa','USA')
  ) AS t(type,type1,type2);
```

Below is \d+ of the table:

```
     Column     |  Type  |                       Modifiers                        
----------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id             | bigint | not null default nextval('documents_id_seq'::regclass)
 title          | text   | 
 description    | text   | 
 source         | text   | 
 url            | text   | 
 emaillink      | text   | 
 emailurl       | text   | 
 type           | text   | 
 language       | text   | 
 author         | text   | 
 publisheddate  | date   | default ('now'::text)::date
 comments       | text   | 
 classification | text   | 
 submittedby    | text   | 
 localurl       | text   | 
 type1          | text   | 
 type2          | text   | 
Indexes:
    "documents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I would like a query that returns:

```
Africa - 2   
Chemicals - 2  
China - 2   
USA - 3
```

This is a query likely to get run fairly liberally, so I'd like to avoid expensive queries if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` to pivot the columns into rows and then do a group by to count the occurrences for each type

```
select type, count(*) from (
    select type1 as type from mytable
    union all select type2 from mytable
    union all select type3 from mytable
) t1 group by type
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I only have about 1000 records, so I couldn't easily discern a difference in speed, but went with the full join anyways.

Comment: How would I sort the full join?

Comment: FYI, the full join doesn't actually merge the three columns for some reason.  The output appears to output each column individually.  I saw duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT WORD, COUNT(1) OCCURENCES
FROM (
    SELECT Type FROM TableName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Type1 FROM TableName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Type2 FROM TableName)
GROUP BY WORD;
```

Comment: If I could select both as answers, I would, you were only what...2 minutes behind FuzzyTree?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `ARRAY[]/unnest()`

```
SELECT x, count(x)
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY[type,type1,type2] AS array
  FROM documents
) AS t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.array)
  AS x
GROUP BY x;

     x     | count 
-----------+-------
 USA       |     3
 China     |     2
 Chemicals |     2
 Africa    |     2
(4 rows)
```